# "List index out of range" error even when setting high/no limit

Tags: python, list, indexing, range, reddit

This is not my code just someone trying to get it to work. [Original here](http://www.reddit.com/r/SomebodyMakeThis/comments/1l82ei/smt_a_tool_that_exports_your_saved_reddit_posts/cbxry93) The script first creates a .csv file of all links then converts it into html with the appropriate bookmark data. Problem is it keeps spitting out the "list index out of range" error. if I set the limit to something lower like 20 or 50 then everything work as intended. The .csv file is at 938 lines, setting the limit to 1000 does not work either.

The error message from commandline.

```
 File "export-saved.py", line 72, in <module>
    main()   
   File "export-saved.py", line 68, in main
    converter.convert()   
   File "export-saved.py", line 38, in convert
    urls = self.parse_urls()   
   File "export-saved.py", line 30, in parse_urls
    folder = url[3].strip() 
   IndexError: list index out of range
```

What sets the accepted range of data that I am hitting out of?

On a sidenote it was interesting seeing that Reddit shows less saved links than they actually have.

Addendum: Ok I think I figured out where the problem stems from. So reddit has more links than it shows. In fact it only shows about 300 links but have around 936 links in their server. When the "time" parameter is defined as "all" it means the 300 links that are shown thus the 600 other links are out of range. How can I include them as well? If that is even the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
export-saved.py
Christopher Su
Exports saved Reddit posts into a HTML file that is ready to be imported into Google Chrome.
'''

import csv
import os
import sys
from time import time

import praw
import AccountDetails

## Converter class from https://gist.github.com/raphaa/1327761
class Converter():
    """Converts a CSV instapaper export to a Chrome bookmark file."""

    def __init__(self, file):
        self._file = file

    def parse_urls(self):
        """Parses the file and returns a folder ordered list."""
        efile = open(self._file)
        urls = csv.reader(efile, dialect='excel')
        parsed_urls = {}
        urls.next()
        for url in urls:
            folder = url[3].strip()
            if folder not in parsed_urls.keys():
                parsed_urls[folder] = []
            parsed_urls[folder].append([url[0], url[1]])
        return parsed_urls

    def convert(self):
        """Converts the file."""
        urls = self.parse_urls()
        t = int(time())
        content = ('<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>\n'
                   '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;'
                   ' charset=UTF-8">\n<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>'
                   '\n<H1>Bookmarks</H1>\n<DL><P>\n<DT><H3 ADD_DATE="%(t)d"'
                   ' LAST_MODIFIED="%(t)d">Reddit</H3>'
                   '\n<DL><P>\n' % {'t': t})
        for folder in urls.keys():
            content += ('<DT><H3 ADD_DATE="%(t)d" LAST_MODIFIED="%(t)d">%(n)s'
                        '</H3>\n<DL><P>\n' % {'t': t, 'n': folder})
            for url in urls[folder]:
                content += ('<DT><A HREF="%s" ADD_DATE="%d">%s</A>\n'
                            % (url[0], t, url[1]))
            content += '</DL><P>\n'
        content += '</DL><P>\n' * 3
        ifile = open('chrome-bookmarks.html', 'w')
        ifile.write(content)

def main():
    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='Subot 1.0')
    r.login(AccountDetails.REDDIT_USERNAME, AccountDetails.REDDIT_PASSWORD)
    export_csv = 'URL,Title,Selection,Folder\n'
    for i in r.user.get_saved(limit=500, time='all'):
        if not hasattr(i, 'title'):
           i.title = i.link_title
        export_csv += ("%s,%s,,%s\n" % (i.permalink.encode('utf-8'), i.title.encode('utf-8'), str(i.subreddit)))
    with open("export-saved.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write(export_csv)
    converter = Converter("export-saved.csv")
    converter.convert()
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the main function. The url[3](http://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/2id0y7/til_that_the_license_plate_of_agent_smiths_car_in/) thing is trying to grab a value from that index in a row in the csv.

But look at the second export_csv line in the main function. The string formatting is wrong - it leaves out what should be in the "Selection" column. Add a %s between the two consecutive commas and a value to unpack for the string formatting, and you should be good to go.

(Kindly read the edit below, as the true source of the error is indeed in the string formatting but is slightly more subtle than I originally thought)

---

Edit: more detail incoming. This is probably more than you wanted to know when you asked "what do you mean by unpack?" Skip to the end to eat a fish, or read all the way through to learn more about fishing.

I think the error is in the `main` function. To debug this, I'm going to pull it out by itself and make some changes to it. I'll rewrite the `main` function like this:

```
def debug_main():
    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='Subot 1.0')
    r.login('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
    export_csv = 'URL,Title,Selection,Folder\n'
    for i in r.get_subreddit('all').get_hot(limit=5):
        if not hasattr(i, 'title'):
           i.title = i.link_title
        export_csv += ("%s,%s,,%s\n" % (i.permalink.encode('utf-8'),
                                        i.title.encode('utf-8'),
                                        str(i.subreddit)))

    with open("export-saved.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write(export_csv)

    print 'Complete'
    return True
```

Now instead of doing everything all at once, this function is just going to write the CSV file for us then stop. Remember, we are getting hit with the error when we pass the CSV file over to the converter. That makes me think that we're going to see some malformed data in the CSV, but we will find out.

I also made one other change purely for debugging purposes:

```
for i in r.get_subreddit('all').get_hot(limit=5):
```

The original `for i in r.user.get_saved(limit=500, time='all'):` is what we would want to use in production - but my personal Reddit account doesn't have any saved posts, so it doesn't do much for me. We still end up iterating over PRAW submission objects, which is the important thing for debugging this stuff.

Now let's save this file as `prawbot.py`, make a file named `export-saved.csv` in the same directory, and open up a shell/terminal to do some pythoning. Make sure you're in the same directory as your `prawbot.py`, then start up a python shell.

Let's import our prawbot and see how he does:

```
>> from prawbot import *
>> debug_main()
Complete
True
```

So far, so good. We exported Reddit's five hottest submissions to a CSV (remember: we could have exported those 500 saved submissions we ultimately want by swapping that line back). Let's open up the CSV and see what it looks like.

[image: oh god]

Ok, that's both depressing and malformed. See how the values go awry on the third row? Take a look at the original code one line at a time:

```
export_csv = 'URL,Title,Selection,Folder\n'
```

This is a string with a newline at the end. As you can see from the CSV file, this is the "header row." There's a newline character at the end, so when we add to this string we'll be adding to "the next line down." There are CSV modules that could probably do this more elegantly, but we're talking about the original code here.

```
for i in r.get_subreddit('all').get_hot(limit=5):
```

This gets five PRAW submission objects for us to play with. Whether we've got five hot submissions or five hundred saved ones, a PRAW submission object is a PRAW submission object. This function should be able to handle whatever sort of submission we stuff into it.

We're iterating over each of the submission objects now:

```
if not hasattr(i, 'title'):
       i.title = i.link_title
```

This is checking to make sure we always have a value for `i.title`, but there's a problem with this line: a PRAW submission object ALWAYS has a `title` attribute. This doesn't actually do anything.

Alright, now the next bit is going to add to our `export_csv` string.

```
    export_csv += ("%s,%s,,%s\n" % (i.permalink.encode('utf-8'),
                                    i.title.encode('utf-8'),
                                    str(i.subreddit)))
```

When you have a string and you do `+=` to it, that means "This string is now equal to the original string plus this other stuff." So:

```
>> a = 'cat'
>> b = 'dog'
>> a += b
>> print a
'catdog'
```

The bit of code we're on now is adding a line "underneath" the header row we created (I say "underneath" because the `\n` means "at the end of this string, drop to a new line). Specifically, it is adding this string:

```
"%s,%s,,%s\n"
```

Those %s things mean "Look for a `%` after this string and replace me with the value you find after it." So you could do something like this:

```
>>print "%s %s %s %s %s %s" % ("I", "think", "python", "is", "really", "great") 
I think python is really great
```

Ok, so what are the `%s`'s in our string getting replaced by? Take a look at the values that come after the %. We can see that the first %s is being replaced by the submission's permalink, the second %s is the submission's title, and the third %s is the submission's subreddit.

Ah, crap. Our header row had four values: URL, Title, Selection and Folder. But each line we add is only unpacking **three** values - URL, Title, and Subreddit. The two consecutive commas in `"%s,%s,,%s\n"` basically mean "skip a column when you're writing this line," which means the entry under Selection is always empty. You can see that in the picture of the CSV file we created above - the selection column is empty, except for one case.

Now, looking at the rest of the code - this may be intentional. The indexerror that ultimately trips us up is looking for `url[3]`, which would correspond to the "Folder" column. The blank cell would be in `url[2]`, which doesn't seem to ever actually get used. I cannot fathom out why the author would include a row that is always intentionally blank, but who truly knows what evils dwell in the hearts of men?

Ok, look at our sample CSV again. The data is malformed on the third row. Looking at the original Reddit thread, the real title is "Found a lollipop left in storage, ants ate it and left the packaging behind."

We are dealing with a CSV, which means "comma separated values," which means the parser chokes on any submission that has a comma in it. In this case, "Found a lollipop left in storage" was stored as one value and "left the packaging behind" was stored as the value in the next cell. Then we skipped a cell, just like we always do after we finish with the title, then we wrote the subreddit name in the NEXT cell.

You mentioned that the original script worked fine for 20-50 submissions but choked on anything much larger than that. I bet it's choking the first time it hits a title with a comma in it.

**Skip to here if you're bored**

So, I amend my original answer. The original script does leave the "selection" column blank, but that appears to be by mysterious yet intentional design. The real issue is that anytime you hit a title with a comma in it, the comma-separated file is going to do what comma-separated files are designed to do - separate values. Things will probably work ok if we strip out the commas from our titles before entering them.

We established earlier that this isn't doing anything:

```
if not hasattr(i, 'title'):
       i.title = i.link_title
```

Every submission object has a title attribute. It's a given, and you can count on it being there. Let's replace those lines with this:

```
title = i.title.replace(',', ' ')
```

This takes every `,` in our title and replaces it with a space, then assigns the reformatted string to `title`.

Now when we go to here:

```
        export_csv += ("%s,%s,,%s\n" % (i.permalink.encode('utf-8'),
                                        i.title.encode('utf-8'),
                                        str(i.subreddit)))
```

We want to add our newly reformatted title instead of the submission's original title. We'll change to this:

```
        export_csv += ("%s,%s,,%s\n" % (i.permalink.encode('utf-8'),
                                        title.encode('utf-8'), #note the difference - no i
                                        str(i.subreddit)))
```

Our `debug_main()` function now looks like this:

```
def debug_main():
    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='Subot 1.0')
    r.login('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
    export_csv = 'URL,Title,Selection,Folder\n'
    for i in r.get_subreddit('all').get_hot(limit=5):
        title = i.title.replace(',', ' ')
        export_csv += ("%s,%s,,%s\n" % (i.permalink.encode('utf-8'),
                                        title.encode('utf-8'),
                                        str(i.subreddit)))

    with open("export-saved.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write(export_csv)

    print 'Complete'
    return True
```

Hop back into your python shell and fire it off. If you're getting permission denied errors, you might need to `sudo python`.

```
>> from prawbot import *
>> debug_main()
Complete
True
```

Cool, now let's check out the CSV file.

[image: much better without all that punctuation]

Looking good. Everything now lines up like it should. If you check out the original Reddit submission in row three ([here](http://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/2id0y7/til_that_the_license_plate_of_agent_smiths_car_in/)) you'll see that the title had plenty of commas in it - but they're not causing problems anymore. Change `limit=5` to `limit=1000` and it'll still work, although it'll admittedly take a few moments more.

Let's hop back into the original code and change the real `main()` function to look like our debugged version.

```
def main():
    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='Subot 1.0')
    r.login('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
    export_csv = 'URL,Title,Selection,Folder\n'
    for i in r.user.get_saved(limit=500, time='all'):
        title = i.title.replace(',', ' ')
        export_csv += ("%s,%s,,%s\n" % (i.permalink.encode('utf-8'),
                                        title.encode('utf-8'),
                                        str(i.subreddit)))

    with open("export-saved.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write(export_csv)
    converter = Converter("export-saved.csv")
    converter.convert()
    sys.exit(0)
```

I'm going to stop here, because this should hopefully resolve the index error you're hitting. But I will note that it is driving me absolutely bonkers that the `parse_url` and `convert` methods are opening files and not closing them after they're through.

Comment: Sooo I also forgot to mention that I know nothing about programming aside from a intro course from two years ago. What value for unpack?

Comment: No worries, I've edited some additional info into the original answer.

Comment: That was incredible, thank you so much for taking your time to write such a quality post. I spent about 4 hours last night trying to figure this out while not even knowing the fundamentals of python. Surprised that CSV would choke up on the comma in the sentence, just imagined the creator would have thought of that! I have read the entire thing, don't worry I'll learn to catch my fish! Getting back into programming and learning python is definitely on the to do list.
I'm going to go to sleep before I go down that hole again, will investigate more tomorrow!
Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: Glad to help! That was a sneaky error, so I can definitely imagine doing something like that myself and not catching it if I didn't have enough test data. Good luck getting back in to programming, it's amazing fun and totally worth it.